# My files aren't being pushed because of exceeding files size

Tags: github

So I can't push my changes because of node_modules exceeding file size. I have already deleted node_modules, added .gitignore but no success.

```
remote: error: Trace: df961b64918660d6b95579e8e6279dd53d9d7295f6123835e21eae687d2ecfac
remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.
remote: error: File node_modules/.cache/default-development/14.pack is 148.63 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
To https://github.com/LissMy/Filmgala.git
 ! [remote rejected]   main -> main (pre-receive hook declined)
```

Comment: Are you really sure you want to push your `nodes_modules`? If so, for what purpose? I remind you that globally it is not recommended. @Liss

Comment: No I don't want to push them, I added them accidentally and now can't get rid of it.

Comment: You just need to add them to the `.gitignore` and it will be done ;)